# RemoteApp duplicate Session

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, remoteapp

We have implemented RemoteApp on Windows 2008 R2 to serve out a few programs,everything work fine except one issue,when a user connects to Server a new session opens and a instance of application runs and work correctly but when this session disconnects because of network fault and user reconnects to the server,another instance of app runs in addition of old instance that ran before,so we have to instance of out application that non of them work fine,session hangs and closes automatically,could somebody please help me to solve this problem! I just want to users connect to the existing session and existing instance that they opened before without any new instance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the apps themselves have nothing to do with it (shouldn't but still).

You are wanting to look at a couple of settings.  You can set these via GPO as well, but assuming a single RemoteApp server, the GUI is easy enough.

In the `Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration` right click on `RDP-Tcp` and choose `Properties`.

In there click on the `Sessions` tab and verify the settings are what you want them to be:

[image]

Then close that screen but leave `Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration` open and verify that `Restrict each user to a single session` is set to **Yes**

[image]

Comment: Thank you TheCleaner but it wont solve my problem because i have tried it before,for solving this problem i assume two solution, first configure GPO to immediately log off the disconnected session, second configure RemoteApp to run application just when a user logs on not when he or she connects to a disconnected session that is log on currently, but i am not sure about second solution and i don't know how can i do this,

Comment: Best I can tell you is that the ABOVE works for every RemoteApp I've deployed.  Users get disconnected, and they get reconnected to the same session.  That's the first thing you need to verify, that they are reconnecting to the same RDP session, not necessarily that they are opening the same app instance.  You can verify this is in the session manager.  Your "2nd question" in your comment just now almost says that the application itself isn't very "Remoteapp" friendly.  Is it a custom written in-house app?

Comment: yes that's true i can verify that users connect to the same RDP session but not the same application instance that they ran before,its a custom application but absolutely not written in-house,it deveoped buy more than 30 programmer and its wildly used national-wide

Comment: Are you certain its the RDP session that gets disconnected and not the app itself?  Meaning, do a normal RDP session, not a remoteapp.  Then launch the app on the desktop.  Now disconnect from the session (hit x and close it, don't logoff).  Now reconnect via normal RDP.  Is the app still running on the desktop?

Comment: yes session disconnect because of temporary link failures on the WAN link between Clients and RemoteApp server,all i need is just a way to tell to windows that just launch the application only and only when a user logs on

Comment: There's nothing within RemoteApp or RDP to do what you are asking though.